# Synchronized with a dummy object instead of this

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

I've come across code like the following several times

```
class Foo {
   private Object lock = new Object();

   public void doSomething() {
      synchronized(lock) {
         ...
```

What I'm interested in is why a lock object is created instead of writing `synchronized(this)`? Is it there to enable sharing the lock? I vaguely remember reading that it is an optimization. Is that true? Also, does it, in some context, make sense to have the lock declared as `final`?

Comment: This question is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3369303/1343161

Answer (score 25, accepted):

1. Synchronizing on `this` is discouraged because if the object itself is used as a lock from the outside it would break the internal synchronization. Also, remember that `synchronized` methods are also using `this` as a lock, which may cause an unwanted effect.
2. Declaring the lock `final` is recommended to prevent a situation in which a lock object is reassigned inside a `synchronized` block, thus causing different threads to see different lock objects. See this other question: [Locking on a mutable object - Why is it considered a bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9622315/locking-on-a-mutable-object-why-is-it-considered-a-bad-practice/9622347)

Answer (score 5):

Imagine a scenario where you have `thread1` and `thread2` access `method1`, `thread3` and `thread4` access `method2`. Synchronizing on `this` would block `thread3` and `thread4` if `thread1` or `thread2` are accessing `method1` which should not happen as `thread3` and `thread4` have nothing to do with `method1`. An optimization for this is to use two different locks instead of locking on the whole class instance.

Here is a nice paragraph I found on JavaDoc that reflects this:

> Synchronized statements are also useful for improving concurrency with
>   fine-grained synchronization. Suppose, for example, class MsLunch has
>   two instance fields, c1 and c2, that are never used together. All
>   updates of these fields must be synchronized, but there's no reason to
>   prevent an update of c1 from being interleaved with an update of c2 —
>   and doing so reduces concurrency by creating unnecessary blocking

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a lock from the java.util.concurrent package 
This may provide more optimized locking, for instance - using a [ReadWriteLock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReadWriteLock.html) will let all readers to access without waiting.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Full working example of "ReentrantReadWriteLock".

```
 public class DataReader  {
 private static final ReentrantReadWriteLock readWriteLock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();
 private static final Lock read = readWriteLock.readLock();
 private static final Lock write = readWriteLock.writeLock();
 public static void loadData() {
  try {
   write.lock();
   loadDataFromTheDB());
  } finally {
   write.unlock();
  }
 }

 public static boolean readData() {
  try {
   read.lock();
   readData();
  } finally {
   read.unlock();
  }
 }

 public static List loadDataFromTheDB() {
     List list = new ArrayList();
  return list;
 }

    public static void readData() throws DataServicesException {
     //Write reading logic
    }
}
```